# Does the javascript debugger in Safari 6 have the ability to de-minify javascript?

Tags: javascript, debugging, safari, javascript-debugger, safari6

In the Chrome debugger under the "Sources" tab, there is a little "{}" button at the bottom that will de-minify minified code and make it human readable (turn on "pretty printing"), as well as allow the developer to set breakpoints, etc. I believe earlier versions of Safari also had this ability, but I haven't found anything similar in Safari 6... Does anyone know if Safari 6 has this ability?

Comment: You probably would need to use a tool like Fiddler or Charles to replace the file with an un-minified file.

Comment: Safari used to have this ability on its own before Apple changed the debugger all around in Safari 6. I'm guessing (hoping) the feature was just _moved_ somewhere else...

Comment: They say it happens automatically. But its not happening.

Answer (score 1):

In Safari on Windows under the Scripts tab in the Developer Tools you have the equivalent **{}** "Pretty Print" icon which will do what you want.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that I was asking about Safari _6_ (which no longer has the Chrome-style debugger, as in your screenshot). I've edited my original post to be more specific.